# Can an nginx location directive match the entire url?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have nginx set up on my server, but am still fairly new to nginx. I am curious if a `location` directive can match the *entire* url (eg `http://myserver.com/mypage` - not just `/mypage`). I see the following in the access.log:

> [IP] - - [19/Aug/2023:14:08:26 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "http://myserver.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0"

So I would imagine I can get `http://myserver.com/` in nginx.conf?

Comment: See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) - but [the location directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) matches against a normalized URI with the scheme, domain name, and query string removed.